# How to transform R code to string?

Tags: r

I would like to transform `c('1','2', 'text')` into a character vector with only one elemenent `c('1','2', 'text')`.

I have tried this:

```
> quote(c('1','2', 'text'))
c("1", "2", "text")
```

but

```
> class(quote(c('1','2', 'text')))
[1] "call"
```

and this:

```
> toString(quote(c('1','2', 'text')))
[1] "c, 1, 2, text"
```

which removes all the punctuation (while I would like to keep the exact same string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`deparse` is for converting expressions to character strings.

```
deparse(c('1','2', 'text'))
#[1] "c(\"1\", \"2\", \"text\")"

cat(deparse(c('1','2', 'text')))
#c("1", "2", "text")

gsub("\"", "'", deparse(c('1','2', 'text')))
#[1] "c('1', '2', 'text')"

deparse(quote(c('1','2', 'text')))
#[1] "c(\"1\", \"2\", \"text\")"
```

Also look at `substitute`

```
deparse(substitute(c(1L, 2L)))
#[1] "c(1L, 2L)"
```

Comment: using `cat` and `deparse` together was a smart one.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely works with my example, but not with this `gsub("\"", "'", deparse(c(1L ,2L)))`

Comment: @d.b that returns `[1] "c('1', '2')"` while I would expect `[1] "c(1L, 2L)"`

Comment: Thanks, seems to me that `gsub("\"", "'", deparse(substitute(c(1L, 2L))))` is the most generalizable then (in my original code I have a bunch of different vectors).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this :

```
  convert_vecteur <- function(vector){
    if(is.numeric(vector)){
      char<- paste0("c(",paste(vector,collapse = ","),")")
    } else {
      char <- paste0("c('",paste(vector,collapse = "','"),"')")
    }
    return(char)
  }

  convert_vecteur(c('1','2', 'text'))
  #[1] "c('1', '2', 'text')"
  cat(convert_vecteur(c('1','2', 'text')))
  # c('1', '2', 'text')
```