# R: display vector in input format

Tags: r

Is there an R function that displays a vector in 'input' format?

For example if

`x <- sprintf("%s",seq(1:3))`

Then the function would produce

```
>unknown_function(x)
[1] c("1", "2", "3")
```

Comment: What is wrong with R's current output gotten from just typing `x` and pressing `ENTER`?

Comment: I'm using the output to create a vector of numbers and removing some of those numbers from the new vector.  The output doesn't have commas.

Comment: `deparse(x)` OR `gsub("\"", "'", deparse(x))`. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942377/7128934)

Comment: this is most likely an XY problem. `toString(x)` has commas

Comment: toString removes the quotation marks

Comment: `dput()` I reckon. Duplicate is literally the first result on Google when searching for the title of your question.

Comment: Yes - that works

Answer (score 1):

As per d.b's comment

```
unknown_function <- function(x){cat(deparse(x))}
```